# How to make SDL play FLTP samples (AAC)?

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, aac

The tutorials  showed this way,

```
SDL_AudioSpec   wanted_spec, spec;
wanted_spec.freq = aCodecCtx->sample_rate;
wanted_spec.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;
wanted_spec.channels = aCodecCtx->channels;
wanted_spec.silence = 0;
wanted_spec.samples = SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;
wanted_spec.callback = audio_callback;
wanted_spec.userdata = aCodecCtx;
SDL_OpenAudio(&wanted_spec, &spec);
```

It doesn't work, apparently the samples are floating points and sdl audio spec format is 16 bit samples. How to make SDL work with floating point samples?

Answer (score 1):

Most people typically use [libswresample](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2resampling_audio_8c-example.html) (part of FFmpeg) to convert from fltp to s16.

Comment: Thank you, bro. libswresample does the job.